# Lista ordenada PHP+AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou com o seguinte problema desde ontem, montar uma lista ordenada conforme irei buscando dados no banco. Me sugeriram fazer com ajax, fiz com a ajuda de um colega do forum até certa parte. Porem, na busca com o banco ele não me retorna nada. Sempre da undefined, acredito que ele não esteja buscando no banco.

Segue codigo em ajax e o php

Codigo AJAX

```
$('#buscar').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'busca.php',
      data: {
        id: $('input[name=id]').val()
      },
      success: function(data){
        $('.table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+data.nome+'</td></tr>')
      }
    })
    return false
  })
```

Codigo PHP

```
    $
<?php


    $host='localhost:C:/bd_relatorio/clipp.FDB';
    $dbh=ibase_connect($host,'SYSDBA','masterkey');
    $stmt = 'SELECT NOME, ID_CLIENTE FROM TB_CLIENTE';
    $sth = ibase_query($dbh, $stmt);


    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = ibase_query("SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE LIKE '%".$id."%'");
    $row = ibase_fetch_row($sql);
    die(json_encode($row));
?>
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que a sua consulta retorna resultados, em princípio, seu problema é que o retorno do AJAX interpretado pelo JavaScript é uma `string` e você está tratando como `JSON`.

Para resolver isso, adicione a propriedade `dataType='JSON'` ao `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON", //<-- define que o tipo de retorno será tratado como JSON
    // restante do código
```

ou realize o *parse* com `JSON.parse`

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(json.nome);
```

Qualquer uma das soluções deve resolver o seu problema de `undefined`.

Ps.: seu código é vulnerável a [SQL Injection.](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). [Leitura complementar](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection)

**Update**

Existe outra situação a ser aborda. Quando você está usando o seguinte trecho de código:

```
ibase_fetch_row($sql);
```

O retorno do PHP é um array similar a este

```
array(1) { 
    ["nome"]=> string(14) "Gabriel Heming" 
}
```

Logo em seguida, você está adicionando à variável `$retorno['NOME']`. Ou seja, seu array se tornou isso:

```
array(1) { 
    ["nome"]=> array(1) { 
        ["nome"]=> string(14) "Gabriel Heming" 
    } 
}
```

Logo, o índice `NOME` não é necessário. Você pode fazer exatamente assim:

```
$retorno = ibase_fetch_row($sql);       
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Ps. 2: O fechamento da tag em PHP (`?>`) é melhor ser omitida.

**Update 2**

Agora que você atualizou o código PHP, remova o cifrão que está no início do PHP e qualquer outro caracter ou espaço em branco. Deve retornar apenas a string do JSON.

```
    $ //<-- remova qualquer caracter que esteja antes da abertura de tag do PHP.
<?php
```

Comment: Esse codigo vai rodar localmente, mas obrigado pelo aviso. Eu tentei passar ele como JSOn, agora ele n da nenhum retorno haha

Comment: $('#buscar').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'busca.php',
          dataType:"JSON",
          data: {
            id: $('input[name=id]').val()
          },
          success: function(data){
            $('.table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+data.nome+'</td></tr>')
          }
        })

Comment: @ProgMen adicione o console.log(data) no `success` e veja qual é o retorno no console. De toda forma, adicione um `callback`  `error` para verificar caso ocorra algum erro. Outro ponto, é usar o firebug (hoje nativo do firefox) e verificar as requisições, ver o que está retornando pela requisição ajax.

Comment: Poderia mostrar lagum codigo de apoio ? Pois sou iniciante em php, ajax entao só estou utilizando pois muitas pessoas recomendaram, nao sei muito bem

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: retorno in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\busca.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
null O console retornou isso.

Comment: Você terá que postar o restante do código `busca.php`, pois, ali informa linha 14, seu código tem apenas 7 linhas.

Comment: Tinha um pequeno erro no codigo, agora o console me retorna exatamente o dado que eu quero, porem ainda nao exibe na tela.

Comment: O erro está na exibição do ajax, porque o dado retorna correto, oque pode ser ?

Comment: Eu atualizei a resposta, mas o seu PHP mudou bastante do exemplo anterior. Aquele cifrão (`$`) não pode estar lá.

Comment: em qual linha ? postei o codigo inteiro php

Comment: Eu atualizei a resposta inteira. Se o código que você está postando aqui é o mesmo que está testando, deve resolver seu problema

Comment: resolveu! obrigado. Agora esta dando outros erros que ainda nao tratei haha, vlw!

Answer (score 0):

É só utilizar o comando `SQL` Order By:

```
$sql = ibase_query("SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE LIKE '%".$id."%' ORDER BY ID_CLIENTE ASC");
```

Desta forma o select irá trazer os dados de forma ordenada.

**Explicação:**

Utilizando o comando `order by` você irá ordenar os valores de uma coluna de forma ascendente(ASC) ou descendente(DESC).

```
SELECT "nome_coluna"
FROM "nome_tabela"
[WHERE "condição"]
ORDER BY "nome_coluna" [ASC, DESC];
```

**Exemplo 1:**

```
SELECT Store_Name, Sales, Txn_Date
FROM Store_Information
ORDER BY Sales DESC;
```

**Exemplo 2:**

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY Country ASC, CustomerName DESC;
```

Comment: Entao jonathan, o problema é que quero fazer uma pesquisa por vez, e nao todas entende ?

Comment: No caso de um ID especifico?

Comment: exato. Busca a busca ele iria mostrando info de cada id

Comment: Existe diversos cenários para isso. Poderia me descrever melhor o que acontece ao retornar e como é feita a consulta.

Comment: Isso aqui é pra eu gerar um "relatorio" de vendas, entrar com os ids dos pedidos e exibis algumas informacoes dele em tabela pra ser impressa. Porem estou construindo usando o cliente como base, pois depois é só eu alterar o sql, pois o banco ainda n esta pronto.